# If I want to create a unique forum, should I try to build it from wordpress or from scratch?

Tags: php, wordpress, web

I have a idea of building a unique forum. This forum would focus on academic lives of international students and scholars from China. I want it to have the following features:

- Signup/signin
- Allow admin to create "main thread" of academic area such as CS, Chemistry, Maths,etc.
- Allow user to write posts under each "main thread".
- Personal pages for every users which provides basic messaging and friends system between users.
- Simple but stylish layout(This is the main reason that I want to build it on wordpress because I just love the style.)

I am very new to web designing and building. I want to now is it possible to build this function on wordpress or is it easier to just build everything from scratch? Excuse me for my bad English. I would really appreciate your helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wordpress isn't best suited for this.

Since you are looking for a learning related portal, you should consider something dedicated.

Take a look at a [atutor](http://atutor.ca/). I found it to be very well designed. It is a dedicated learning management tool.

It does not have all the features you require, like dedicated user pages, but you can write modules to extend it.

It will give you a lot of features out of the box. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

It is not easier to build everything from scratch. In fact, if you're new to web design this will prove to be a pretty challenging task in Wordpress or any other framework.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a unique forum you should build from scratch. Using forums from `wordpress` is like reusing a CMS which is not unique. But if you are new to web designing you can look at `mybb, phpbb` forums which is good to start with and offers the functionalities you need.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a quick fix on creating a new webpage, consider [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/). It is one of the fastest ways to get your site up and running. That way, you can just focus on the backend logic for creation of forms.

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with joomla then you can use Kunena forum http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/communication/forum/7256 . It can fulfill your requirement.